# Cascading combobox with SQL parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an overloaded method to fill a combobox. I'm trying to use this to cascade some comboboxes on my Windows Form, but my code doesn't seem to be passing the SQL parameter to the SQL Server stored procedure properly when filling the second combobox using the value of the first as the parameter.

I've tried many variations for this method and none have worked. Initially I was receiving an error stating that the stored procedure was expecting a parameter but it wasn't passed to it. I've now got the code to a point where I get no errors, but it still doesn't populate the second combobox.

I've tried using the combobox.Text value and combobox.SelectedValue. I've also tried adding the parameter to my code with `Parameter.Add` and `Parameter.AddWithValue` but it doesn't affect the outcome.

My SQL Server stored procedure takes the name of a game as the parameter and returns all characters for that game:

```
SELECT c.CharacterName
FROM dbo.Characters c
JOIN dbo.Games g ON g.GameID = c.GameID
WHERE g.GameName = @GameName
```

I have two versions of my C# method. The first populates the first combobox with the names of the Games in the database:

```
private void fillCombobox(ComboBox cmb, string scmd, string dispmem)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server = (local); Database = DBName; Integrated Security = SSPI; "))
    {
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(scmd, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        da.Fill(ds);

                        cmb.DisplayMember = dispmem;
                        cmb.ValueMember = "ID";
                        cmb.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second version of my method should use the text of the game combobox and pass it to the stored procedure as the parameter to return only characters from the selected game:

```
private void fillCombobox(ComboBox cmb, string scmd, string dispmem, string param1)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server = (local); Database = DBName; Integrated Security = SSPI;"))
    {
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(scmd, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameName", param1);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        da.Fill(ds);

                        cmb.DisplayMember = dispmem;
                        cmb.ValueMember = "ID";
                        cmb.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then call both methods like this:

```
fillCombobox(cmbGame, "sGetGames", "GameName");
fillCombobox(cmbName, "sGetGameCharacters", "CharacterName", cmbGame.Text);
```

My aim is that the game selected in `cmbGame` will be passed to the `sGetGameCharacters` stored procedure as a parameter. SQL Server then returns all characters for that game and displays the `CharacterName` in the second combobox.

I've tried other variations based on similar questions I've seen on here but nothing has worked, so I'm all out of ideas and new to C#.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in the end. The code is fine. It was the underlying data in the database that was the issue. When the form loads the first value on the games combobox had no characters, so the character combobox looked like it wasn't populating, but it was.